# Asynchronuous call to GnomeKeyring using GObjectIntrospection

Tags: introspection, gobject, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, gobject-introspection

I am writing a gnome-shell extension that shows the current balance of prepaid-cards like phones (or electricity). As this needs credentials for the given services, I do not want to store the password in gsettings, but as entry in gnome keyring.

Currently, I use the synchronous way asking the keyring for login and password using

```
const GnomeKeyring = imports.gi.GnomeKeyring;

GnomeKeyring.unlock_sync(null, null)
// the variable 'id' is a concat of login '@'webservice url
var attrs = GnomeKeyring.Attribute.list_new()
GnomeKeyring.Attribute.list_append_string(attrs, 'id', id)
var result = GnomeKeyring.find_items_sync(
                GnomeKeyring.ItemType.GENERIC_SECRET, 
                attrs
             )
if (result[0] != GnomeKeyring.Result.OK) return
log('  => password '+result[1][0].secret)
log('     keyring id  = '+result[1][0].item_id)
log('     keyring  = '+result[1][0].keyring)
```

This sync. approachs weak point is, that the keyring needs to already be open or a password dialog is prompted. When starting gnome-shell with auto-login, this synchronous call blocks actually starting the shell at all - so no possibility to enter the keyring password.

The [Gnome Developer Wiki](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-keyring/stable/gnome-keyring-Search-Functionality.html#gnome-keyring-find-items) names the asynchronous methods

- GnomeKeyring.unlock
- GnomeKeyring.find_items

but both are not found in [the javascript environment](https://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/GnomeKeyring.html).

Where can I find the GnomeKeyring-Gir file under fedora23 to confirm the lack of the asynch functions missing? 
How can I achieve an asynchronous keyring-opening and retrieve of the passwords?
Does anybody see a completely different, possible approach?
Every little helps...

Comment: Have you considered using [libsecret](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/0.16/js-examples.html) instead of GnomeKeyring?

Comment: Hey @JayStrictor, actually I haven't. Wanted to use the standard Gnome environment (as it is for a Gnome shell extension) and didn't look for alternatives instead GnomeKeyring. Do you know if libsecret supports asynchronous calls - with sync. calls my extension blocks the whole gnome shell when starting up.

Comment: It says "libsecret replaces libgnome-keyring" on the [website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret). So I assume that for new projects you should probably use libsecret instead. Furthermore libsecret has an asynchronous [`unlock()` method](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Secret-1/Secret.Service.unlock.html). Although the doc says that the asynchronous method "may block indefinitely", but that could be a copy&paste error. So I would just try it!

Comment: Also note that libsecret uses GnomeKeyring as a backend.

Comment: Hey @JayStrictor, your solution works great. Do you want to formulate it as an answer, so I can accept and give you the kudos you deserves? :-)

Comment: Thanks :) Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using [libsecret](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/) instead of libgnome-keyring.
It says "libsecret replaces libgnome-keyring" on the [project website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret) of libsecret. So for new projects you should probably use libsecret instead.

Furthermore, libsecret has an [asynchronous `unlock()` method](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Secret-1/Secret.Service.unlock.html). Although, at the time of writing, the docs say that the asynchronous method "may block indefinitely". But that could be a copy&paste error. So I would just try it!

Also note that libsecret uses GnomeKeyring as a backend, so you would actually use GnomeKeyring, although in conjunction with a more versatile library.